# Rails 7: javascript_include_tag issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 7 app and I'm NOT using the `javascript_importmap` or the `@hotwire/stimulus`. I have a custom js file in here `app/javascript/custom/feature/categories.js`. The file loads with this `import './custom/feature/component.js';` inside the application.js. The issue is that I want to load that file only on a specific html.erb view page.

So I'm trying to do it like this: I place this `<%= javascript_include_tag 'app/javascript/custom/feature/categories.js' %>` inside the .html.erb view file but I'm getting this error:  `The asset "app/javascript/custom/feature/categories.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.`

Any ideas what Im doing wrong??

Comment: Is your custom js file `app/javascript/custom/feature/categories.js`  using the @hotwire/stimulus ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Shah Nawas Khan... No its not!

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 7, to add a custom JS using the asset pipeline, first let Rails asset pipeline know where your custom JS files are by adding the reference in the `app/assets/config/manifest.js`.

```
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
```

This tells Rails to search for your JS files in any folders in `app/javascripts` directory. (This code should already be there by default, if not then add this line.)

Then add the `javascript_include_tag` on the top of any pages as:

```
   <%= javascript_include_tag "custom/feature/categories" %>
```

Make sure, your customer JS file are stored in the folder `/app/javascripts` folder.

Comment: You are mixing / and \ directory separators

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Shah Nawas Khan. I've updated the description please check it out again.